# Oracle sql dbms_scheduler.create_job pass value to sh

Tags: sql, oracle, sh, jobs

I want to create simple oracle sql dbms_scheduler.create_job to run sh file:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name             => 'my_job1',
   job_type             => 'excecutable',
   job_action           => 'bin/some/some.sh',
   enabled              =>  TRUE,
   comments             => 'GOOD');
END;
```

Before starting some.sh I want to add parameteres to sh file:

```
echo sayHello from $argument_from_sql
```

How I can get "argument_from_sql" from Oracle sql when I am starting job. Where is any possibility?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments, for example

```
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job(
     job_name=>'MY_SHELL',
     job_type=>'EXECUTABLE',
     job_action=>'/path/my_shell.sh',
     enabled=>false
     );

  DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value('MY_SHELL',1,'myarg');
```